# How to add multiple terms to an if @cond in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm going to ask probably a simple question but I cannot find any solution in the internet.
I have the following mongo db query.
I want the field "iocScore" to be set according to a certain logic.
if the field  "$score" equal to 0, set the field  "iocScore" to 1, else set the field "iocScore" with the value of "$score" multiple by 10.
I was able to that with the query below

```
"iocScore" : {
      "$cond" : {
        "if" : {
          "$eq" : ["$score", 0]
        },
        "then" : 1,
        "else" : {
          "$multiply" : ["$score", 10]
        }
      }
    }
```

but now I want to expend the term of the if and ask if the "$score" field equals 0 or 0.0 or null then set the "iocScore" to 1.
I tried to this it like this:

```
  "iocScore" : {
      "$cond" : {
        "if" : {
          "$score" : {
            "$in" : [0, 0.0, null]
          }
        }
      },
      "then" : 1,
      "else" : {
        "$multiply" : ["$score", 10]
      }
    }
```

but I keep getting a syntax error.
any idea?

Comment: Within a `$cond` you can use this [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) aggregation operator.

Comment: you have a syntax error because `then` and `else` are outside `$cond`

Comment: it works with `$in` as expected https://mongoplayground.net/p/2GgOQZEqCIV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[]` defines an array. Elements within the array should be the **same** type.

Join the three eq expressions with [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator.

Comment: Thanks I did that and It helped:   "iocScore" : {
      "$cond" : {
        "if" : {
          "$or" : [
            {"$eq" : ["$score", null]},
            {"$eq" : ["$score", 0]}
            {"$eq" : ["$score", 0.0]}
          ]
        },
        "then" : 1,
        "else" : {
          "$multiply" : ["$score", 10]
        }
      }
    }